# Продолжение цикла(парсинга) при отсутствии элемента

Tags: python

Не могли бы подсказать как сделать так, чтобы при отсутствии элемента парсинг продолжался? Вопрос о Python.

```
    time_info = soup.find_all(class_="row block")[2]
    info_20 = time_info.find_all(class_="section__info")[0]
    info_21 = time_info.find_all(class_="section__info")[1]
    info_22 = time_info.find_all(class_="section__info")[2]
```

То есть во время парсинга на странице не всегда есть info_22, выдается ошибка и парсинг завершается. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Можно обернуть info_22 в try-except https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/2.11.php

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В твоем случае если элемент будет не найден, выбьет ошибку - `KeyError`.
Обращаешь нужный блок кода в `try/except`:

```
try:
    time_info = soup.find_all(class_="row block")[2]
    info_20 = time_info.find_all(class_="section__info")[0]
    info_21 = time_info.find_all(class_="section__info")[1]
    info_22 = time_info.find_all(class_="section__info")[2]
except KeyError:
    pass # Здесь можно отправлять лог в терминал, что элемент не найден
```

Если метод `find()` вернет None и ты у него будешь вызывать какие-то методы (.find(), .text, find_next_sibling()), получишь - `AttributeError`